# Double Variable storing Negative values after a calculation

Tags: java

I'm trying to attempt a question in which the following code snippet is producing the wrong result. I'm assuming some data mishandling but not able to get to the correct answer.

```
int v=1000000000;
System.out.println(Math.round(3*v*Math.cos(Math.toRadians(30))));
```

Output          :  -1121474575

Expected Output :   2598076211

Answer (score 3):

`Integer.MAX_VALUE` is 2,147,483,647, but `v*3` is 3,000,000,000, resulting in a negative number due to integer overflow.

If you want to work with integers of that magnitude you must use `long`.

Comment: Okay.  I got the result by using v in double. Thank you very much.